# Dynamically add rows based on size of collection

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render a set of cards into rows of 3. Currently the collection size is 8. So it should render into 3 rows, first two is filled with 3 cards, last row has 2 cards.

Currently I'm able to render the 8 objects into 3 rows. However, instead of creating a row under the previous, it creates the new `row div`  inside the current one, making the layout out of line.

I think the conditional for the closing `div` statement is giving me problems.

Code that renders the cards:

```
    <% @count = 0 %>
    <% @col_count = 0%>
    <div class="card-group">
        <% @user.articles.each do |article| %>
            <% if @count == 3 %>
                <% @count = 0%>
            <% end %>

            <% if @count == 0 %>
                <div class="row">
            <% end %>
            
                <div class="card col-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Test Card</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a placeholder card.</p>
                    </div>           
                </div>
            
            <% if @count == 0 && @col_count == 2 %>            
                </div>
                <% @col_count = 0 %>
            <% end %>

            <% @count = @count + 1 %>
            <% @col_count = @col_count + 1 %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better if you use `each_slice` instead, it should look like this:

```
        <% @user.articles.each_slice(3) do |articles| %>
            <div class="row">
            <% articles.each do |article| %>
            
                <div class="card col-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Test Card</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a placeholder card.</p>
                    </div>           
                </div>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

Please correct me if I make any mistake.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Didnt know you could do that.